# How to get MODIS data with 3 band and step to change hdf file to colored map?

Tags: web-mapping, modis, band, hdf

I just convert hdf file to tiff with MRT but my result is grayscale map. How to get MODIS data with 3 band and step to change hdf file to colored map?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't get it. Because MODIS gives a some product(LST,NDVI.EVI..etc).The products have been produced by using multi-spectral bands ,but output is one layer.you want at least three bands to colour composite.I think you want to visualize some area as a colour map.Please use multi-spectral bands products of that area(LANDSAT,MODIS..)